# UTF-8 character not showing properly in tmux

Tags: prompt, tmux, utf-8

I use `♪` character in my `zsh` theme's for prompt. But in tmux, my prompt was behaving weirdly, showing extra spaces, like this:

```
♪ ~   I can type from here
♪ ~ Instead of here like in zsh, and sometimes when I do stuff like cd
♪ ~   cd ~
♪ ~ cdcd /
♪ ~ ^^These 2 chars just show up but are not actually part of command and not delete-able
```

I recently discovered that I can set tmux encoding to utf8 by `set-window-option -g utf8 on`. Doing that, the space problem was gone but `♪` character changed to `_`. How can I get my `♪` back in `tmux`?

My zsh-theme:

```
PROMPT='%{$fg_bold[cyan]%} ♪ %{$fg[blue]%}%c%{$fg_bold[blue]%}$(git_prompt_info)$(git_remote_status)%{$fg_bold[blue]%} % %{$reset_color%}'
```

Comment: I couldn't get `set-window-option` to work for me `not found cmd`. Please, could write exact steps to reproduce it.

Comment: I used the tmux conf [here](https://gist.github.com/snuggs/800936) (its also used [here](https://github.com/hoelzro/dotfiles/blob/master/tmux.conf)). It looks like tmux is converting every character that is not ASCII into `_`, when I set that option.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Starting tmux with `u` flag solves this issue

```
tmux -u
```

I've created an alias of tmux in my zshrc

```
alias tmux='tmux -u'
```

Comment: Thanks for the flag! It was so frustrating with all the gibberish when using tmux and nvim would go crazy with powerline! This solved the issue! Thanks again.

Comment: For those who what to know why, check [here](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1), `-u` `flag explicitly informs tmux that UTF-8 is supported`

Comment: Interesting. I thought setting `set -g utf8 on` in `~/.tmux.conf` would solve this issue, but apparently it didn't. Using the flag explicitly when calling `tmux` does works though. Thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of hassle!

Comment: For what it's worth, this recently broke for me, turns out it was due to me adding LC_ALL=C to my config, which forced ascii encoding.

Comment: Just a note. The setting seems not to be saved in the session. After detatching, one should/can use `tmux -u attach` to set the session to UTF-8.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks for the flag part, but we can also set the below to the profile rc (e.g. `.zshrc` or `bashrc`) file

```
export LC_ALL=en_IN.UTF-8
export LANG=en_IN.UTF-8
```

With this option set, no need to use the -u flag.

Comment: This works only if pasted above `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`

Answer (score 0):

If u use diffrent shell like "fish" or sh u can change enviroment variable of tmux

`$ tmux setenv 'LC_ALL' 'en_IN.UTF-8'`

`$ tmux setenv 'LANG' 'en_IN.UTF-8'`

`$ tmux show-environment`

```
DISPLAY=:0.0
-KRB5CCNAME
LANG=en_IN.UTF-8                          <-enviroment variable
LC_ALL=en_IN.UTF-8
SSH_AGENT_PID=1269
-SSH_ASKPASS
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-tGUWJ874wmOG/agent.1193
-SSH_CONNECTION
VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/Jai_BholeNath/.tmux.conf
-WINDOWID
XAUTHORITY=/home/Jai_BholeNath/.Xauthority
```