# Tmux doesn't render some symbols properly

Tags: bash, fonts, tmux

I'm using [powerline-go](https://github.com/justjanne/powerline-go) to generate the bash prompt. It works fine in the tilda (also Konsole), like so:

[image]

Which is fine. However, the moment I open tmux it becomes messed up:
[image]

Basically, the segment seperators end up shown as underscores. This is pretty annoying, and I'm not able to understand why tmux refuses to render my fonts the same way as a regular terminal.

I'm using Fantasque Sans Mono, but I see the same behaviour with other fonts.

In fact, it seems tmux doesn't render any utf-8 symbols properly. I tried

```
echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac'
```

this prints the euro sign in the normal terminal, but again an underscore in tmux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved it by adding the following to my .bashrc

```
export LC_ALL=en_IN.UTF-8
export LANG=en_IN.UTF-8
```

Comment: Didn't work for me though :/ what's the logic behind this?

Comment: Ahh, it's to do with `tmux` knowing (or not) that UTF-8 is supported. More information (and solutions) here: https://askubuntu.com/q/410048/20096